# PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels (Anaconda clean installed 20230504)

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda3

Referencing [this](https://PackagesNotFoundError:%20The%20following%20packages%20are%20not%20available%20from%20current%20channels:).

When I tried:

```
conda install --file requirements.txt --verbose
```

I am stilling getting "PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels (Anaconda clean installed 20230504)" with a clean install of Anaconda on 20230504. I tried suggestion from referenced link:

```
conda config --append channels conda-forge
```

But still a lonnng list of packages not available, MANY of them are very COMMON for example **"numpy" and "flask"**.
[image]

I then tried install individually, it worked:

```
conda install numpy
```

Also, the good old pip also works!

```
pip install -r requirments.txt
```

What's going on with Conda?